# Connect to mongodb on Azure VM from another Azure VM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure

I'm working on a NodeJS project that using Azure VM to deploy. Currently, the database and server are in one single VM. With this implementation, I can easily access to the database by this `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost")`

Now, I'm trying to move the database into another VM. I have created an endpoint for port 27017, and configured VNET to VNET connection between 2 virtual network. But I still get the error `Connection refused` when trying to connect to the database.

Does anybody have experience in configuring mongodb on Azure VM?

Comment: Which type of VMs you are using, classic or ARM? And which platform you are using? Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm using a Linux classic VM

Comment: Did you configure your `mongodb.conf` to allow for remote mongodb connections?

Answer (score 0):

You'll make your life easier (and you'll save money) by using subnets inside one VNET for network partitioning instead of using separate VNETs.

If you use separate VNETs you either have to configure a VPN connection over the Internet, or configure VNET peering (which they price per GB transferred). Unless you have very special requirements (like you're running a dedicated ExpressRoute to an on-premise network), you want to have everything inside the same VNET.

The quickstart-templates typically create one VNET each; that's for demonstration purposes. In a production environment you have one single VNET with several subnets if necessary. If you look at the templates, it's quite easy to see where you specify the reference to an existing VNET.

Comment: I am planing to keep the database in one VM and there will be several of other VM from other locations connecting to it. 
I have already configure a VPN connection between 2 VNET by following this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/
But I still cannot connect to the database in other VM

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an SSH Tunnel in your mongodb server VM, and connect the the mongodb server via this tunnel. You can refer to he similar scenario at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-your-own-dedicated-mysql-server-for-your-azure-websites/.

After installing the mongodb in the VM, please try to following commands, which works fine on my side at last:

- `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT`
- `sudo netstat -anltp|grep :27017`
- `sudo ssh -fNg -L 27017:127.0.0.1:27018 azurevmuser@servername`
- Create an endpoint for the port `27018` in the dashboard of the VM in Azure management portal

Then you can connect to the mongodb via the following code:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://<your_server_vm>.cloudapp.net:27018/test');
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
     console.log("we're connected!")
    });
```